# Can we get the position of any device accurately with its IP address? If yes, which is the best API for that?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

How can I get the position of any device accurate to city/street level, with its IP address. Is there any API's powerful enough to do that?

I researched and found google's Geolocation tools somewhat provide something—but not something very powerful and that couldn't be trusted 100%.

Can we find out the position (with IP & any other data we fetch) on our own? Is there any 'hybrid' APIs which combines different IP location finding tools(like google geolocation, ip2location or others) to increase accuracy?

This question may not be a good question, but I just needed some hints or links to the new apis/technologies. Which will definitely help me.

Note: Answers that are specific to one browser only, some location only are also welcome.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt you would get city/street level by IP.

Comment: @epascarello , I have got the city name around 55% correctly through google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible to make it always work fine. For example in Poland in one of our mobile and phone operator (Plus GSM) when you use mobile internet it always will show Warsaw as your IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure because at this time I'm sitting here in Warsaw center, but I think it wont help much. But to be sure I will check it later, and gave you answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your ip and location details with this url :
http://ip-api.com/json

Check this link. It might help you.
https://www.ipify.org/

```
$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
```

Also check this link for getting location details.

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

Comment: It is usefull, but not for location.. :( , IP only. But thanks

Comment: @SarathMohan please see another link of my answer. I have edited it.

Comment: I already checked ipinfodb, it is not as good as google geolocation. But simple and easy to use

Comment: You are only going to be able to get as close as your ISPs location which may be nowhere near the person.

Comment: @SarathMohan check this url. I think It excellently what you want. http://ip-api.com/json

Comment: I will check  ip-api.com, thnks @dharmesh